# Storing and fetching cities that user have visited (for millions of users) mysql - php

Tags: mysql, list, store

I want to store cities that users have visited. In profile page all the cities that user have visited will be listed. And there will be a function where users can search 'who visited that city' (there can be a multiple city search)

I'm planning to do a many-to-many relationship.

```
Table Users
-----------
UserID
UserName
...


Table Cities
-------
CityID
CityName
....


Table City_Relations
-----------
UserID
CityID
```

In the profile page I can run a simple query to get cities.

```
select c.cityname FROM city_relations cr left join cities c on ( c.cityid = cr.cityid ) where cr.userid = 'USERID'
```

And in the search page to get users who visited the selected city(ies);

```
select u.username FROM city_relations cr left join users u on ( u.userid = cr.userid ) where cr.cityid = 'CITYID'   ( there may be cr.cityid = '1' or cr.cityid = '2' and so on; or in()/find_in_set()  )
```

So far everything is ok. My question is how efficient this is? Assuming that there are 100 millon users, each user can have hundreds of cities in city_relations table. Let's say 100 cities for each user, there will be 10 billion rows in that table where will run insert/delete and select - join queries.

If this way works ok, what should I keep in mind for best performance? Indexes on tables are enough?
If this way may cause problems, what other ways do you suggest?

What do you think about 'not storing all relations in different rows and keeping them into one field'?

```
For example;
-----------
UserID
CityIDS (separated by commas)
```

Comment: good luck getting 100 millon users

Answer (score 0):

It is much better if you can store the `city` in a different row. Although there exist builtin functions in mysql like `find_in_set()` but it will not be flexible enough if you try another database server. And also you are talking billions of rows not million. So Efficiency of the query is the most important here.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to index both columns in city_relations. Since UserID,CityID is presumably the unique, primary key for the table, you don't need an additional index for UserID (indexes are B-trees, so any prefix of an indexed set of columns is also indexed), but you'll need an index for CityID by itself.

I agree with John that you should keep the cities in separate rows. find_in_set() can't take advantage of the index, so it will have to search every row and perform a complicated string search.

Comment: So you are saying adding PRIMARY KEY (`userid`,`cityid`). There are indexes for ids in 'users' table and 'cities' table. For this case, adding KEY `userid` (`userid`), KEY `cityid` (`cityid`) after primary key changes anything? (for better performance)

Comment: What I suggest is `PRIMARY KEY (userid, cityid), KEY (cityid)`. You don't need `KEY (userid)` because this is already provided implicitly by the primary key. Adding this extra key will just use redundant space and time.

Comment: I did exactly what you told. Created and indexed the table as you told. There are 1.5m rows in user table and 100m rows in relation table. Now 


`SELECT u.username
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN city_relations c
ON (u.userid = c.userid)
WHERE c.cityid = 87 order by u.userid desc limit 100`


this query returns up to 8 seconds. How can I reduce it? Usign a foreign key can reduce?

Comment: I assumed userid is the primary key of the users table. If not, it should be. Also, how many rows in city_relations have cityid 87? The time may be from sorting the results if they're large.

Comment: Yes, userid is the primary key with cityid. There are 1 million rows with cityid 87. With that query results came so slow. I changed the join and it now returns faster.(0.10 seconds) But I have a different problem with that table using `group by` and `having` `SELECT userid, count( userid ) AS cnt
FROM city_relations
WHERE status ='1'
GROUP BY userid
HAVING cnt = 10
LIMIT 10` this query basically doesn't return anything, it's too slow so I restart the mysql server.

Comment: Additional information; status field is enum with 0 and 1, it also has separate index. When I add a couple of rows with status 3 (altered the status table too), results came fast. So I assume first query returns slow because there are about 50 million rows with status 1.